# Angular 12 with .NET and Windows Domain Authentication

Tags: asp.net, .net, angular, windows-authentication

So I've trying to setup Angular login with Windows Domain Authentication and the backend is hosted with .NET.
Every resource about that on the internet suggest adding interceptor on Angular side:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
   req = req.clone({ withCredentials: true });
   return next.handle(req);
}
```

and registering it in app.module

```
providers: [
   { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CredentialsInterceptor, multi: true}
],
```

then a sample http request in a service

```
this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'user')
```

But making a request
[returns 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz9f9.png) with cors policy error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

And what is strange, necessary cors headers have been already added on backend. Since I'm working on frontend only, is there anything that could be added on Angular side?
What I'm expecting is a Windows Domain login window showing after making an http request.
Any help will be appreciated